# How to test logging(log.Println) in Golang?

Tags: testing, go

How to test below the code in Golang?

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    log.Println("hello world")
}
```

Comment: That's how you learn that global variables is evil and one must have followed the dependency inversion principle instead.

Comment: The `log.Println` function is already tested. Don't try to test other packages' code, make you're code independently testable.

Comment: @JimB The question is not "_How do I test log.Println?_" (which, as you rightly point out, would be silly) but instead is "_How do I test that my main is calling log.Println properly?_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program writes to the `log` package standard logger which writes to standard error. Compile and run your program and see what appears on standard error.

Comment: The question is asking for a way to write an automated test - not how to manually demonstrate that it works.